# Pig: How to send all Tuples to a UDF to be Processed without Grouping them? Or how to convert tuples into a Bag without Grouping?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera

This is what I am trying to do:

```
A = LOAD '...' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
    col1:int
    ,col2:chararray
);
B = ORDER A by col2;
C = CUSTOM_UDF(A);
```

CUSTOM_UDF goes through the tuples, which need to be in order. The UDF would output one aggregate tuple for every few input tuples; i.e., I am not returning tuples in a 1:1 fashion.

Essentially:

```
public class CustomUdf extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        Aggregate aggregatedOutput = null;

        DataBag values = (DataBag)input.get(0);
        for (Iterator<Tuple> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Tuple tuple = iterator.next();
            ....
            if (some condition regarding current input tuple){
                //do something to aggregatedOutput with information from input tuple
            } else {
                //Because input tuple does not apply to current aggregateOutput
                //return current aggregateOutput and apply input tuple
                //to new aggregateOutput
                Tuple returnTuple = aggregatedOutput.getTuple();
                aggregatedOutputTuple = new Aggregate(tuple);
                return returnTuple;
            }
        }
    }
    // Establish the output Schema as a tuple
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
        ...
        return new Schema(
            new FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input), 
            tupleSchema, 
            DataType.TUPLE));
    }

    /** This inner class is simply a wrapper for the output tuple **/
    class Aggregate {
        //member variables

        public Aggregate(Tuple input) {
            //set member variables to value of input's fields
        }
        public Tuple getTuple() {
            Tuple output = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(5);
            //set tuple's fields to values of member variables
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been able to do something like

```
A = LOAD '...' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
    col1:int
    ,col2:chararray
);
B = ORDER A by col2;
C = GROUP B BY col1;
D = FOREACH C {
    GENERATE CUSTOM_UDF(B);
}
```

However this doesn't seem to retain the ORDER BY, and I can't figure out how to order `d` as I keep getting invalid field projections.

Plus I don't need to group by (it just happens to work in this use case) and would just like to send the B alias as a bag of tuples to the CUSTOM_UDF.

How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem with how CustomUdf is written.  Based on your description it sounds like this should be an EvalFunc < DataBag >, not EvalFunc < Tuple >.  Then in the implementation, as you iterate through all the tuples in the input bag you append the accumulated tuples to a DataBag that is returned at the end of the method.

Your Pig code would then look like what I have below.  I don't think ORDER BY will retain the order across separate statements like you have it.  It will however retain the order within a nested FOREACH like below.

```
A = LOAD '...' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
    col1:int
    ,col2:chararray
);
B = FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) {
   A_ordered = ORDER A BY col2;
   GENERATE FLATTEN(CUSTOM_UDF(A_ordered));
}
```

The exec method would look something like the modified version below.  Note the changes I made.

```
public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException { // different return type
    Aggregate aggregatedOutput = null;

    DataBag result = BagFactory.newDefaultBag(); // change here
    DataBag values = (DataBag)input.get(0);
    for (Iterator<Tuple> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Tuple tuple = iterator.next();
        ....
        if (some condition regarding current input tuple){
            //do something to aggregatedOutput with information from input tuple
        } else {
            //Because input tuple does not apply to current aggregateOutput
            //return current aggregateOutput and apply input tuple
            //to new aggregateOutput
            Tuple returnTuple = aggregatedOutput.getTuple();
            aggregatedOutputTuple = new Aggregate(tuple);
            result.add(returnTuple);  // change here
        }
    }
    return result; // change here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am curious, however, as to memory problems that would occur if this DataBag was filled with lots of rows? Could you comment on that?

Comment: DataBag is capable of spilling to disk, so I doubt you will run out of memory.  There are two things to consider.  One is the bag you are receiving and the other is the bag you are constructing.  Regarding the first case: My understanding of the way the DefaultAbstractBag works is that it will try to keep the contents in memory, but if a threshold is reached it will spill to disk to free up memory.  When iterating through the bag contents it will read from local disk.  Assuming Pig is handing you a DefaultDataBag then I believe this is how it will behave.

Comment: Regarding the second case: constructing the output bag.  Again, the bag can spill to disk if it gets too large.  If you do start seeing OOM issues you can explicitly call spill(), say every 1 million records or something.  Of course all these spills mean extra overhead.

Comment: One optimization you can make is to implement AccumulatorEvalFunc<DataBag>.  Here you implement accumulate instead of exec.  The accumulate is passed the tuples from the input bag one by one.  So this may avoid inefficiencies with receiving a large bag.  Since Pig knows that you don't need the whole bag there is no need to spill the bag to disk (at least in theory this is my understanding).  But this doesn't avoid the issue with spilling the output bag.  I don't know a way to avoid this.  Pig doesn't have a Streaming UDF interface or something like that afaik.

Comment: I implemented this and tested it on a million rows and received a java heap error. Would you please refer to this question and give me your opinion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567307/why-does-this-pig-udf-result-in-an-error-java-heap-space-given-that-i-am-spil

Comment: Added my comments there.  Hope it helps.  If not I will see what else I can think of :)

Answer (score 0):

This not possible. The closest you could come would be to use `GROUP A ALL` and then process the resulting bag, but this is not optimal if you have a large dataset. It's not clear why you  need to do this.  If you do need to group by `col1`, you can order those tuples using a nested `FOREACH`:

```
B =
    FOREACH (GROUP A BY col1) {
        C = ORDER A BY col2; -- here, A refers to the bag of tuples in this group
    GENERATE
        group AS col1,
        CUSTOM_UDF(C);
    };
```

Again, I can't quite tell what you are trying to achieve, but this might get you going in the right direction.